# Which prosthetic tools are associated with which shinobi/warrior/soldier in lore?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

In the game, the prosthetic tools you can find, collect and integrate into your prosthetic arm were all once used by other shinobi, warriors or soldiers. The ones with previous users I am aware of are:

- The shinobi Orangutan originally used the Shinobi Axe of the Monkey, which becomes the Loaded Axe when integrated into the prosthetic.
- The kunoichi Kingfisher originally owned the Slender Finger, which becomes the Finger Whistle upon integration into the prosthetic.
- The samurai Gyoubu Masataka Oniwa once owned a spear, the dilapidated remains of which are now Gyoubu's Broken Horn. It becomes the Loaded Spear upon integration into the prosthetic.
- Robert's Firecrackers were once peddled as wares by Little Robert and his father, the Armored Warrior. They become the Shinobi Firecracker when integrated into the prosthetic.

I would like to know which other prosthetic tools are associated with which other characters, and possibly also their intended function in lore if they have a special one.